# Android Custom Tabs support library for sdk 21

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an android app and recently I had to change the sdk version to 21 but I can't find a support library for custom tabs.
I tried

```
 compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:21.1.0'
```

but if I compile it, I get

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:21.1.0
```

Any idea how I to solve this?

Any tip/idea would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Android SDK is up-to-date (Google repository specifically), you won't have access to old versions of Custom Tabs library. You can look for them in your SDK folder:

```
sdk$ find . -name \*customtabs\*.aar
./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.0.0/customtabs-23.0.0.aar
./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.0.1/customtabs-23.0.1.aar
./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.1.0/customtabs-23.1.0.aar
./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.1.1/customtabs-23.1.1.aar
./extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.0/customtabs-23.2.0.aar
```

You should probably compile with SDK 23, use support libraries in version 23, but target API level 21 if really needed.